# DBT Is there a way to add configurations to all tests in a single model

Tags: yaml, dbt

I want all tests within one model to only test recent data. I can apply a where clause to the whole project or to a folder like so:

```
tests:
  my_project:
    marts:
      finance:
        +where: "date_column = current_date"
```

But if I do go one level deeper and put it on a model:

```
tests:
  my_project:
    marts:
      finance:
        fct_revenue_events:
          +where: "date_column = current_date"
```

I get an warning and it doesn't seem to work:

```
[WARNING]: Configuration paths exist in your dbt_project.yml file which do not apply to any resources.
There are 1 unused configuration paths:
- tests.my_project.marts.finance.fct_revenue_events
```

How can I apply my where clause to all tests within one model only?